# Stream Manipulation for outputting object data in different formats

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

Say I have an employee object with the following data members:

```
class Employee {

private:
    int _id;
    std::string _name;
    std::string _address;
    std::string _city;
    std::string _state;
    std::string _country;
    std::string _phone;
    double _salary;
...
}
```

I would like to output it two different ways:

XML

```
<Employee>
     <id>12345</id>
     <name>Jack Dough</name>
     <address>24437 Princeton</address>
     <city>Dearborn</city>
     <state>Michigan</state>
     <country>USA</country>
     <phone>303-427-0153</phone>
     <salary>140000</salary>
</Employee>
```

and JSON-like:

```
id: 12345
name: Jack Dough
address: 24437 Princeton
city: Dearborn
state: Michigan
country: USA
phone: 303-427-0153
salary: 140000
```

How would I be able to do so with stream manipulators?
For Example:

```
Employee* employee = new Employee(12345, "Jack Dough", "24437 Princeton", "Dearborn", "Michigan", "USA", "303-427-0153", 140000.00);
cout << toXML << employee;
cout << toJSON << employee;
```

Comment: Or would my best approach be to just to have class functions
`ostream& Employee::toXML()`
`ostream& Employee::toJSON()`

I like the stream manipulator part, because it looks a bit better to me, and also, the challenge seems cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, unless you *really* need to implement this as a separate manipulator, consider other routes. Two obvious possibilities would be a custom locale, or just a function that does the formatting and returns the result as a string. The former would look something like:

```
std::locale myLoc(std::locale(), XML_formatter);
cout.imbue(myLoc);

cout << employee;
```

This makes the formatting style persistent for the stream in general. If you really need to mix different styles in the same stream, the function version is a lot simpler:

```
std::string toXML(Employee const &e) { 
    std::stringstream ret;

    ret << "Employee>\n<id>" << id << "</id>"
        << // ...
    return ret.str();
}

// ...
cout << toXML(employees[i]);
```

If you truly have no choice but to implement this as a separate manipulator, you'll need to store a flag to indicate the current format in the stream. Streams provide a memory management interface in the form of `xalloc`, `iword` and `pword`. Basically, `xalloc` allocates one word for you. `iword` gives  you access to that word as a reference to a long, and `pword` gives you access to it as a reference to pointer to void. In your case, you apparently only need one or two bits, so you probably want to use `iword` and define a couple of bits to specify the formatting for the type. Your `toXML` and `toJSON` manipulators will set the appropriate bits, and your `operator<<` will read them to control its behavior. It's clumsy and ugly, but it does work if you're willing to put a little effort into it.

Comment: I had thought of that, and it is a viable solution, to overload operator<< with a flag.
It's not outputting to the same stream, rather, outputting to two different streams, the XML to file, and the JSON to the console, which is why i thought the stream manipulators would be the best solution.

However, it seems like the best solution would be just to return an ostream& of the class data as a member function.

Comment: I didn't even knew about the possibility with the locale, thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

> How would I be able to do so with stream manipulators?

I'll show you how, but keep in mind that this is not the way to go here. Dedicated (member) functions or some fancy OOP pattern is a better approach.

That said you can attach arbitrary data to stream objects. For that, you first need an "id" for that data. You get that using `std::ios_base::xalloc`:

```
static int formatId = ios_base::xalloc();
```

With the number returned you can get (write) access to a `long` via the reference returned by `std::ios_base::iword`. (There's also `std::ios_base::pword` to get a `void *`.)

Then, a stream manipulator is just something that's callable with a stream (reference), returning another stream reference:

```
ostream & toFoo(ostream & stream) {
  stream.iword(formatId) = 1;
  return stream;
}
ostream & toBar(ostream & stream) {
  stream.iword(formatId) = 2;
  return stream;
}
```

(*Attention: Evil magic numbers, replace with better design!*)

Here I just set up a "flag" so that finally, in the output function (operator), I can check which manipulator (if any) was used last:

```
struct FooBar {};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & stream, FooBar const &) {
  switch (stream.iword(formatId)) {
    case 1: stream << "foo"; break;
    case 2: stream << "bar"; break;
    default: stream << "wild foobar";
  }
  return stream;
}
```

Well, that's it. I tested with:

```
int main() {
  FooBar f;
  cout << f << toFoo << " " << f << endl;
  cout << f << toBar << " " << f << endl;
  cout << f << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[(Live here)](http://ideone.com/BEynhV)

Comment: That is a beautiful solution. Too bad stream manipulators were not conceived with this process in mind.
You happened to answer a question i didn't ask as well, which was: How to associate a flag in a stream chain and associate it in the overloaded `operator<<`, so thanks for that.